# How to keep a history of edit of Entities in a JPA application

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

A JavaEE and JPA application need to keep a record of all the changes made by the user.

Currently, for all the entities, there are fields to record createdBy and lastEditedBy properties. Yet, the requirement of recording all edits is not possible with those properties.

What is the best way to record the history of all edits for a particular entity?

I do not use Spring.

Comment: Can't you use database trigers to track the changes?

Comment: Can you please give a link of reference?

Comment: This will depend on wich database server you are using. For postgresql you can have a look there : http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/

Comment: What is the purpose of such an change? how exactly would you like to use the stored information?
Another very important question IMO is how frequent the changes are? And yet another question, is the application under high load (in other words, are the additional interactions with the database are acceptable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Javers](https://javers.org/blog/2017/12/javers-vs-envers-comparision.html) which is db and framework agnostic tool for maintaining operation history.

> There are two big differences between JaVers and Envers:
>
> 1. Envers is the Hibernate plugin. It has good integration with Hibernate
>      but you can use it only with traditional SQL databases. If you chose
>      NoSQL database or SQL but with another persistence framework (for
>      example JOOQ) — Envers is not an option.
>
>    On the contrary, JaVers can be used with any kind of database and any
>      kind of persistence framework. For now, JaVers comes with repository
>      implementations for MongoDB and popular SQL databases. Other databases
>      (like Cassandra, Elastic) might be added in the future.
> 2. Envers’ audit model is table-oriented. You can think about Envers as
>      the tool for versioning database records.
>
>    JaVers’ audit model is object-oriented. It’s all about objects’
>      Snapshots. JaVers saves them to the single table (or the collection in
>      Mongo) as JSON documents with unified structure.

You can also achieve this using triggers and storing object differences.

Edit: 
JaversAuditableAspect for any kind of repository.
It defines the pointcut on any method annotated with the method-level @JaversAuditable annotation. Choose it if you have repositories that are not managed by Spring Data.

```
@Bean public JaversAuditableAspect javersAuditableAspect() { return new JaversAuditableAspect(javers(), authorProvider(), commitPropertiesProvider()); }
```

Comment: THank you. Javers seems to be the best option. Googling showed that it needs Spring. Can I do it without Spring?

Comment: Yes, it can be used without Spring as well. The approach is available in documentation.
Editing my answer to give you a brief.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate's Envers to audit your entities. It allow you to keep track of ALL changes made to entities - even deleted ones. Most probably you are already using Hibernates (as JPA provider) so integration should be a no problem.

https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/

Comment: I use JPA with EclipseLink, not hibernate